# Strange Behaviour with Error Message 'RangeError: Invalid time value'

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, express

I'm writing a simple timestamp API with Express. Basically when a user types in a date in 'normal' format, a json object with the unix format and normal format is shown. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
timeRouter.route('/:time')
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    let time = req.params.time;
    let unixTime = Number(time);

    if (unixTime) {
      res.json({'unix': unixTime, 'natural': moment.unix(unixTime).format('MMMM D, YYYY')});
    } else {
      let timeDate = new Date(time);
      console.log(`timeDate: ${timeDate}`);
      let isoTimeDate = timeDate.toISOString();
      console.log(`isoTimeDate: ${isoTimeDate}`);
      if (moment(isoTimeDate).isValid()){
        res.json({'unix': Number(moment(isoTimeDate).format('X')), 'natural': moment(isoTimeDate).format('MMMM D, YYYY')});
      } else {
        res.json({'unix': null, 'natural': null});
      }
    }
  });
```

If for example, I enter the URL 'localhost:3000/January 10 2015', the API works as expected and I get:

```
{
  "unix": 1421712000,
  "natural": "January 20, 2015"
}
```

The problem is that I get this in the console:

> timeDate: Tue Jan 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)
>
> isoTimeDate: 2015-01-20T00:00:00.000Z
>
> timeDate: Invalid Date
>
> RangeError: Invalid time value
>
> at /app/routes/timeRouter.js:19:34
>
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>
> at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>
> at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>
> at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>
> at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
>
> at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
>
> at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
>
> at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)

The first two lines make perfect sense because of the two console.log lines of code I have. The weird thing is after this happens, the variable `timeDate` is logged to the console again with an invalid date value and the causes the error message. Line 19 refers to `let isoTimeDate = timeDate.toISOString();` Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: It might be helpful to point out which line is line 19 in app/routes/timeRouter.js.

Comment: Also, you should log the value of `time` before your call to `new Date(time)` to see what exactly is being passed to the `Date` constructor.

Comment: @mscdex thanks I've made the edit to include info on which line is line 19

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It turns out, a second favicon.ico request was being made and that was causing the error as obviously 'favicon.ico' isn't a valid time value